# How do I change white pixels to black if they are surrounded by black pixels?

Tags: imagemagick

The zoomed-in image below shows part of a black-and-white scan of a text document. Notice that there are some unwanted white pixels within the black letters. Is there a way to use ImageMagick to remove white pixels that are completely surrounded by black pixels?

[image: Scanned letters]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a median filter. A median filter sets a pixel to the median value of its neighbors (so in case of black and white, to the most frequent). So a white pixel among black pixels turns black and disappears.

```
convert input_image -median 3 output_image
```

[image]

As you see above the big speckle near the edge in the `n` won't let go to easily since part of the background is also included in the median sample.

Using `-median 6` makes it disappear but this may have other impacts in your image (rounding of shapes for instance):

[image]

For very small spots there is also a `-despeckle` operator.

Comment: What is the meaning of the argument given to `-median`? In `-median 3`, what does `3` represent?

Comment: I believe it is the radius in pixels of the area from which pixels are sampled.